# Boto3: Empty Datapoint from AWS instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I wanted to write a Python script which will fetch my EC2 CPU utilization. While using get_metric_statistics() method, the output response shows like this [image].

As far as I know the 'Datapoints:[]' array shouldn't be empty. It should return something to get the CPU load %. My code is

```
import boto3
import sys
import datetime


client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Dimensions=[
        {
        'Name': 'InstanceId',
        'Value': 'i-***********'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=600),
    EndTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=120,
    Statistics=[
        'Average',
    ],
    Unit='Percent'
)

print(response)
```

Any help on what is wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it takes the default region, which is "ap-southeast-1" (it's in the .aws/config). In the .aws/credentials file, it automatically takes the secret key & access key that was used while configuring the api. **If they conflict, the datapoint returns empty.**

Solution:
 1. Create a new profile for every region. configure the region in .aws/config. Mine looks like this

```
`[default]
region = ap-southeast-1

[profile nv]
region = us-east-1
[profile prod]
region = us-east-1
~                  `
```

nv and prod is usermade profilenames.

2. Enter the name instead of default

   `session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')`
3. Enter the secret key & access key in the same way in .aws/credentials.

You can use `aws configure --your_profile_name` to create the profiles inside the config & credential files

Answer (score 0):

To use percentile statistics you must first enable detailed monitoring.

[Amazon EC2 Metrics and Dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I did that without enabling it !